# Updating progressbar from IntentService?

Tags: android

I'm trying to update the progressbar which is integrated in my notification bar but I can't seem to get it working. I kind of have the idea why it is not working but I have no idea of how to solve it. this is the code:

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService{

     public DownloadService() {
        super("DownloadService");


    }

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           ctx = getApplicationContext();
           root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder-videos/");
           if(root.exists() && root.isDirectory()) {

           }else{
               root.mkdir();
           }          
           notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
           PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, null, 0);

           notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "App", System.currentTimeMillis());
           contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.progress_layout);
           notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
           notification.contentView = contentView;
           notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
           contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, 0, false);        
           contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_text,"Downloading...");  

       }

        @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

        int count;
        String full_url = URL + intent.getStringExtra(VIDEOS);

        try {
            URL url = new URL(full_url);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            File file = new File(root.getPath(), intent.getStringExtra(VIDEOS));

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;
            contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_text,"Downloading " + intent.getStringExtra(VIDEOS));  
            while ((count = input.read(data)) > 0) {
               total += count;      
               notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100,(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile), false);       
               Log.e("totaltotal","" + (int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
               output.write(data, 0, count);


            } 
            notificationManager.notify(1,notification);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("PRINTSTACK","STACK:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I know I have to call : notificationManager.notify(1,notification); within the while loop and I've tried but it freezes the app and crashes it. Is there any other way to notify the notification manager of the progressbar updates.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use `notificationManager.notify(1,notification);` only a few times

as in :

```
int lastProgressUpdate=0;
while(...)
{
    if(progress%5==0 && progress!=lastProgressUpdate)
    {

         notificationManager.notify(1,notification);
         lastProgressUpdate=progress;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it with 5 it still kept freezing the UI. Tried with 10 same albeit to a lesser extent I could still pull the notification bar down but it would go slowly and freezing.

Comment: is there some kind of NotificationListener that listens for updates and notifies the NotificationManager.

Comment: it's updating it as before, but when i pull the notification bar down it keeps freezing...

Comment: is there any other way other than using a while loop for updating the progressbar while the file is being downloaded!!

Comment: this code(the while loop) is inside an IntentService and inside onHandleIntent which runs as a separate thread from the main one which should be fine.

Comment: I did some more tweaking I moved the NotificationManager and Notification create code from the onCreate method to the onHandleIntent method it seems to be running smoother now but it still when the app starts and the notification icon appears that the download started, when i pull down the notification bar it freezes a little and then it eventually comes down. The progress bar gets updated fine. If I could just eliminate that freezing part completely.