# Progress Bar % completed (download) Display in Android

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I  have a problem with Progress Bar showing % of download completed. I have a service class in which the downloading takes place. I can get the start time and end time of download from this class. In Main Activity on clicking a button I have to show the progress %. I heard that its possible through AsyncTask but I have no clue about how it works. Please help me with some sample code example related to this. Thanks

Comment: See this example, it also provides **CODE**, http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-asynctask-example.html Just download it and learn new things.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog

Comment: hi please look at this it might be helpful to u
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712370/updating-progressbar-from-intentservice and may this also be helpful http://toolongdidntread.com/android/android-multipart-post-with-progress-bar/

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer AsyncTask for this.

Here's an example

```
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
// instantiate it within the onCreate method
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
mProgressDialog.setMessage("A message");
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

// execute this when the downloader must be fired
DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
downloadFile.execute("the url to the file you want to download");
```

here's the AsyncTask

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/file_name.extension");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

This can be done using Download from Service as well as Download Manager class. Refer this question for  [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog.).

**EDIT**

The percentage completed is what you actually publish in the progress dialog. If you want to display the percentage, you may use this (total * 100 / fileLength).

```
int percentage =  (total * 100 / fileLength);
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.setText("" + percentage);
```

Use this code to display the percentage in the desired textview.

Comment: hi, there is only a progress dialog which is displayed. The progress is not displayed. I did the same thing like how you said.

Comment: this will give u the percentage (total * 100 / fileLength). you may accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

here is a class

```
public class XYZ extends Activity {

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private Button startBtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startDownload();
        }
    });
}

private void startDownload() {
    String url = "http://.jpg";
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    int count;

try {

URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();

int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/some_photo_from_gdansk_poland.jpg");

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
return null;

}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
     Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
     mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}
```

}
}

and here is a xml file

http://pastie.org/4265745

Best of luck
Aamirkhan I.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. The progress is still not shown. I did the same thing like how you specified.

Answer (score 0):

## Progress bar with counting %

### //you can use these method after Firebase Storage upload task

```
 final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
   progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
   progressDialog.show();
   progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
   StorageReference reference = storageReference
                                  .child("images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());

  reference.putFile(filePath).addOnProgressListener(new 
                                OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot 
                                      taskSnapshot) {
                                    double progress =                  
             (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                                    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+ 
                                 (int)progress+"%");

                                }
                            });
```

## Result

[image]